# NextJS - rendering only on server or .. both

Tags: javascript, next.js

So I have a users.js JSX file with some exported component:
`... return <MainContainer keywords="users"> export default Users`

- when using SSR/SSG, I get the users HTML (just a bunch of `<li>` tags) in the browser as expected
- the browser **also** receives a `.next/static/chunks/pages/users.js` with digested/lower-level representation of that React component as client-side js. This gets imported via `<script>` in HTML.

**AssumptionL** that js file is for rendering, CSR-style, of the users dataset, into HTML.
Because it contains stuff like
`_components_MainContainer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3 ...  react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["jsxDEV"])("li", ....`

So, clearly the js in `<script>` can create `<li>` elements **as well as the server**. I think it can create the whole page content, if executed.

**Question**: why the apparent duplication of effort? Does the browser, with SSR/G, get BOTH HTML and js and js ALSO runs producing HTML - surely not? I am using **getStaticProps** in my users.js

If the assumption why we have a compiled/digested React js (under .next/static) in the browser, is incorrect, then **why** does NextJS need this file pulled in via `<script>` ?

Comment: That's the process of rehydratation. The HTML sent by the server is "dead" => it's not a React app. Rehydratation is the process that will make it "alive", by running some JS code that will basically initialize your React app.
This way the user gets the visual result immediately, and then React takes the lead to make the page dynamic a few ms later.

Answer (score 1):

Next.js is used for server-side rendering of the react apps. React with another framework like angular and vue.js are client-side frameworks, they run in browsers but there are some technologies to run this framework on the server-side, and next.js is a solution for running react application server-side. It also makes react development very simple features of Next.js are:
Server rendering React Apps.
Automatic code splitting and lazy loading.
Built-in CSS support.
Hot Reloading support.